# A function for using in apply() in R

Tags: r, function, apply

Is there anyone know how can I define a function to be used in apply() that return the following value? data[i,data[i,300]].

data[i,300] returns a column number in my data, and I am interested to know the content of this column number for each row.

It's easy to use for loop for addressing this issue as follows:
for (i in 1: nrow(data)) {
value<-data[i,data[i,300]] }

But it takes too much time for 10M observations. I am looking for a fast approach using apply().
I appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: If you have 10 million observations, then each column will have 10 million entries, including the 300th column. This means that you are looking for a function that returns 10 million vectors, each of length 10 million. Your computer would need to have over 800,000 gigabytes of memory to do that.

Comment: Please add a minimal data example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apply does not improve efficiency/speed. apply is pretty comparable to a normal for-loop. Its just a wrapper of for-loop. You need to know exactly what you want, since so far, you are just returning the columns, which is just the data you have. Probably you need to do more than just view the column values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the 300th column has different column numbers for each row and for each row you want to check the value in the column specified by this 300th column.

sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    c1 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), 
    c2 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), 
    c3 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), 
    c4 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), 
    c5 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), 
    d = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)
> head(df)
  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 d
1  o  o  p  b  r 2
2  s  u  w  m  l 2
3  n  e  a  x  o 3
4  c  h  h  q  s 5
5  j  s  h  c  u 1
6  r  j  j  r  f 3
```

Thus for above sample, let's assume the 6th column, column d is the one that gives the column numbers, so the expected output should be `df[1, 2]`, `df[2, 2]`, `df[3, 3]`, `df[4, 5]`, `df[5, 1]`, `df[6, 3]`, which evaluates to `c('o', 'u','a', 's', 'j', 'j')`

To get this we can use:

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df[[6]])] # change 6 with 300 for your case
```